# Are there reasons for keeping fully specialized template in the header?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

If I have a fully specialized template function like:

```
// This stay in the header
template<typename X>
void foo(x b);

// This goes into the source file - any drawbacks?
template<>
void foo(Bar b) {
  ...
}
```

are there reasons to keep it in the header instead of the source file? I would like to keep these in the source files, to reduce the compile times (these specialized functions can get quite big and also they pull a lot of dependencies in the header), but I would like to be aware if there are any trade offs of putting them into the source file.

Comment: If you want other source files to use the template, it must go into a header (although you could place it into another source file and include that source file).  Consider templates as stencils.

Comment: I updated the question: I could use the foo(Bar) in other files, even if I put it into the source file. But I am curious if there are any drawbacks of doing that.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Sorry, no :-) Declaration yes, but the full specialized template can be placed in a cpp file. As OP noted: Header for declaration, cpp for definition of fully specialized file!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fully specialized template, declaration still should be in header (so compiler knows that it doesn't use primary template):

```
template<> void foo(Bar b);
```

but definition can go in cpp file (or stay in header):

```
template<>
void foo(Bar b) {
  //...
}
```

Comment: Are there any drawbacks of putting it into the cpp file?

Comment: @gruszczy the very same ones that non-template functions have. If function definition is in .cpp then optimizer has no knowledge of what it does and cannot inline it and utilize whatever else it can from the definition. But when the function is large the difference is insignificant.

Comment: @ALX23z That makes sense, so smaller functions should like stay in the header.